# Where Should I Map JSON from an API into a JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm building a JavaScript web application that makes a GET request to an API. It transforms the model provided by the API into its own model (a class). Where is the best place to do this transformation?

**Option 1: In the constructor?**
This might be troublesome if I want to create a new user from something other than an API response, since I can only stamp out a `User` from an API response.

```
class User {
  constructor(apiResponse){
    this.name = apiResponse.userName;
    this.date = apiResposne.dateCreated;
  }
}
```

**Option 2: In a static factory method of the class?**
This could be troublesome because different API endpoints may require slightly different mappings. I might have to create other `fromApi` methods based on where the data is coming from.

```
User.fromApi = function(apiResponse) {
    var user = new User();
    user.name = apiResponse.userName;
    user.date = apiResposne.dateCreated;
    return user;
}
```

or, **Option 3: In the service/class that fetches from the API:**
This might be un-DRY if I have multiple fetching methods that have to do this  mapping (or a slightly different version of it).

```
fetch('/user/3').then((apiResponse)=> {
  var  user = new User();
  user.name = apiResponse.userName;
  user.date = apiResposne.dateCreated; 
})
```

Comment: I think it depends on the rest of the architecture of your app. I would tend toward option three, because generally you'll be hitting different endpoints when you're using the user object for a different purpose.

Comment: If possible, try to avoid data transformations altogether. It will make your code much simpler. http://datadictionary.blogspot.com/2010/09/mccrearys-law.html

Comment: Unfortunately, working with a large enterprise  REST API with several different frontends (developed by different teams at different times), data transformations are pretty much unavoidable at this point.

Also, data transformations at least keep a front end and an API loosely coupled. If my API decides to start using a different naming convention for something, I just have to change it in two places (mapping it going in and mapping it going out), rather than changing it in 100 places across 100K LOC.